pow function results in ',' : syntax error
I am using shadertoy.com and the line the error occurred is:
float ang = pow(length(InTexel.rgb - iso2),2.) - pow(dot(vec3,InTexel.rgb),2.);
error: ',' : syntax error
my whole code:
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    // Normalized pixel coordinates (from 0 to 1)
    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;

    vec4 InTexel= vec4(uv.x, uv.y, 0.0, 1.0);

    vec3 iso1 = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    vec3 iso2 = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    float dis = pow(length(InTexel.rgb - iso2),2.) - pow(dot(vec3,InTexel.rgb),2.);
    
    if (dis < 0.3) {
        fragColor = InTexel;
    } else {
        float col = 0.299 * InTexel.r + 0.587 * InTexel.g + 0.114 * InTexel.b;

        fragColor = vec4(col, col, col, 1.0);
    }
}

I was trying to calculate the distance between InTexel.rgb and iso1

dot(vec3,InTexel.rgb) -- that vec3 there seems a bit out of place, no?

@DanMašek my bad didn't see that, thanks, do you know any program that helps with syntax errors better than shadertoy?

No idea, I've only played a little with GLSL. Besides, requests for software recommendations are off-topic on ins site, sorry.
